# Solve a linear equation XA=B using matrix with zero diagonal

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, pseudoinverse

Consider the following problem: given $A,B\in\mathbb{R}^{N\times P}$ for $N>P$, we wish to find $X\in\mathbb{R}^{N\times N}$ such that:
$$XA=B$$

Without further constraint, the solution is given by the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse:
$$X=BA^+=B(A'A)^{-1}A'$$

but I'm interested in a solution $X$ with zero diagonal, i.e., $X_{ii}=0\ \forall i\in[N]$. This is still a linear equation so it can be solved numerically, but is there a way to write the solution $X$ "in closed form"?

EDITED: fixed the wrong ("transposed") definition mentioned in some of the answers below

Comment: Previously asked here (by others) regarding square matrices A,B where there is no solution...

Comment: I don't see how to go from $XA=B$ to the pseudo inverse, as post multiplying by $A'$ results in the singular matrix $(A\,A')$. You gave to pre-multiply by $A'$ by the $X$ is in the way of doing do.

Comment: @JohnAlexiou fixed the expression for X in the unconstrained solution, the problem definition was correct

Answer (score 2):

$
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\diag#1{\op{diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\Diag#1{\op{Diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\frob#1{\left\| #1 \right\|_F}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\p{\partial}  \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\CLR#1{\c{\LR{#1}}}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
\def\gradLR#1#2{\LR{\grad{#1}{#2}}}
$Let $\{e_k\}$ denote the standard basis vectors, replace $\LR{A,B,X}$ by their transposes, and define a $zero$-$one$ matrix $(F)$ with zeros on the diagonal and ones elsewhere.

It will also be convenient to introduce an **unconstrained** matrix $(U)$
and define the following variables
$$\eqalign{
X &= F\odot U &\qiq dX = F\odot dU \\
H &= A^TB,&\quad\quad a_k = Ae_k \\
b_k &= Be_k,&\quad\quad x_k = Xe_k \\
f_k &= Fe_k,&\quad\quad h_k = He_k = A^Tb_k \\
F_k &= \Diag{f_k} &\qiq F_kv = f_k\odot v \\
}$$
and the Frobenius product $(\,:\,)$ with the following properties
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_i\sum_j A_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; \trace{A^TB} \\
A:A &= \frob{A}^2 \qquad \{ {\rm Frobenius\;norm} \}\\
A:B &= B:A \;=\; B^T:A^T \\
A:\LR{BC} &= \LR{AC^T}:B \;=\; \LR{B^TA}:C \\
A:\LR{B\odot C} &= \LR{A\odot B}:C
 \;=\; \sum_i\sum_j A_{ij}B_{ij}C_{ij} \\
}$$
Write the equation as an unconstrained least-squares problem
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= \tfrac12\frob{AX-B}^2 \\
 &= \tfrac12\LR{AX-B}:\LR{AX-B} \\
d\phi &= \LR{AX-B}:\LR{A\;dX} \\
 &= \LR{A^TAX-A^TB}:{F\odot dU} \\
 &= F\odot\LR{A^TAX-H}:dU \\
\grad{\phi}{U} &= F\odot\LR{A^TAX-H} \\
}$$
Solve the zero-gradient condition by utilizing the unique property of the $e_k$ vectors, which distribute across Hadamard products !
$$\eqalign{
F\odot\LR{A^TAX} &= F\odot H \\
\LR{Fe_k}\odot\LR{A^TAXe_k} &= \LR{Fe_k}\odot\LR{He_k} \\
F_k \LR{A^TAx_k} &= F_k h_k \\
x_k &= \LR{F_kA^TA}^{\boldsymbol+}F_k h_k \\
 &= \LR{F_kA^TA}^{\boldsymbol+}F_k A^Tb_k \\
}$$
Thus you can solve for the optimal $X$ matrix one column at a time.
The pseudoinverse is used to solve the columnar equations, since the matrix in parentheses is singular.

You can rework the whole problem in terms of the original **transposed** variables, but the result has transpose operations everywhere and looks much uglier.

Answer (score 1):

Denote by $x_{i\ast}$ and $b_{i\ast}$ the $i$-th rows of $X$ and $B$ respectively. Let $\widehat{x}_{i\ast}$ be the subvector obtained by removing the $i$-th element from $x_{i\ast}\in\mathbb R^{1\times(N-1)}$ and $\widehat{A}_i\in\mathbb R^{(N-1)\times N}$ be the submatrix obtained by removing the $i$-th row from $A$. The problem
$$
XA=B,\quad x_{11}=x_{22}=\cdots=x_{NN}=0\tag{1}
$$
is then equivalent to the system of linear equations $x_{i\ast}A=b_{i\ast}$ and $x_{ii}=0$ for $i=1,2,\ldots,N$. In turn, it is equivalent to the system of linear equations
$$
\begin{cases}
\widehat{x}_{i\ast}\widehat{A}_i=b_{i\ast}\quad\text{for  $i=1,2,\ldots, N$,}\\
x_{11}=x_{22}=\cdots=x_{NN}=0.
\end{cases}\tag{2}
$$
Therefore, *when it is solvable*, one solution (among possibly infinitely many solutions) is given by
$$
\begin{cases}
\widehat{x}_{i\ast}=b_{i\ast} \widehat{A}_i^+\quad\text{for  $i=1,2,\ldots, N$,}\\
x_{11}=x_{22}=\cdots=x_{NN}=0,
\end{cases}
$$
and the systems of equation $(1)$ and $(2)$ are solvable if and only if
$$
b_{i\ast} \widehat{A}_i^+\widehat{A}_i=b_{i\ast}\quad\text{for each  $i$.}
$$

Answer (score 0):

OK, there's a nice answer, which stems from a Lagrangian perspective on the source of the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse solution for the unconstrained case.

The unconstrained diagonal case can be written as solving the following optimization problem:
$${\cal L}=\frac{1}{2}\|X\|^2_F-Y\circ(XA-B)$$
where $Y\in\mathbb{R}^{N\times P}$ are Lagrange multipliers and $\circ$ denotes element-wise multiplication. Taking the derivative $\partial {\cal L}/\partial X$ and equating to $0$ this is solved for $X=YA'$ so that from $XA=B$ we have $Y=B(A'A)^{-1}$ and $X=BA^+$.

Moving over to the constrained diagonal case, now it can be written as solving the following optimization problem:
$${\cal L}=\frac{1}{2}\|X\|^2_F-Y\circ(XA-B)-y\cdot diag(X)$$
where $Y\in\mathbb{R}^{N\times P}$ and $y\in\mathbb{R}^{N}$ are Lagrange multipliers. Taking the derivative $\partial {\cal L}/\partial X$ and equating to $0$ this is solved for $X=YA'+\Delta(y)$, where $\Delta(y)$ is a diagonal matrix with $y$ as the diagonal, so that from $XA=B$ we have $Y=(B-\Delta(y)A)(A'A)^{-1}$ and finally:
$$X=BA^++\Delta(y)(I-AA^+)$$

Now the self-consistent solution for $y$ would be:
$$y=-diag(BA^+)/diag(I-AA^+)$$